# How to implement a barcode scanner that works on a smartphone (iPhone and Android) using zxing in html

Tags: html, zxing

Among the answers to various questions, I checked the answers below and applied them.

Running the app and taking a picture works on Android, but it doesn't work on the iPhone. What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">

    if(window.location.hash.substr(1,2) == "zx"){
        var bc = window.location.hash.substr(3);
        localStorage["barcode"] = decodeURI(window.location.hash.substr(3))
        window.close();
        self.close();
        window.location.href = "about:blank";//In case self.close isn't allowed
    }
</script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" >
    var changingHash = false;
    function onbarcode(event){
        switch(event.type){
            case "hashchange":{
                if(changingHash == true){
                    return;
                }
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                if(hash.substr(0,3) == "#zx"){
                    hash = window.location.hash.substr(3);
                    changingHash = true;
                    window.location.hash = event.oldURL.split("\#")[1] || ""
                    changingHash = false;
                    processBarcode(hash);
                }

                break;
            }
            case "storage":{
                window.focus();
                if(event.key == "barcode"){
                    window.removeEventListener("storage", onbarcode, false);
                    processBarcode(event.newValue);
                }
                break;
            }
            default:{
                console.log(event)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", onbarcode, false);

    function getScan(){
        var href = window.location.href;
        var ptr = href.lastIndexOf("#");
        if(ptr>0){
            href = href.substr(0,ptr);
        }
        window.addEventListener("storage", onbarcode, false);
        setTimeout('window.removeEventListener("storage", onbarcode, false)', 15000);
        localStorage.removeItem("barcode");
        //window.open  (href + "#zx" + new Date().toString());

        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i)){
            //Used for Firefox. If Chrome uses this, it raises the "hashchanged" event only.
            window.location.href =  ("zxing://scan/?ret=" + encodeURIComponent(href + "#zx{CODE}"));
        }else{
            //Used for Chrome. If Firefox uses this, it leaves the scan window open.
            window.open   ("zxing://scan/?ret=" + encodeURIComponent(href + "#zx{CODE}"));
        }
    }

    function processBarcode(bc){
        document.getElementById("scans").innerHTML += "<div>" + bc + "</div>";
        //put your code in place of the line above.
    }

</SCRIPT>
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT id=barcode type=text >
<INPUT style="width:100px;height:100px" type=button value="Scan" onclick="getScan();">
<div id="scans"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you normally do not need to beg for answers here. just politely ask for help, and any community member will likely to assist. please update your question title so people to know what your question is about

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed its access to use camera to scan barcode directly from a website or even a app can't do it, If you want to scan barcode, you need to use their camera app to scan, [more on here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208843) and if you want to link your application to a QR code, you can use their [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to launch an app by scanning a QR code.

But yes, in android, any barcode scanner will work directly from website, even to this date.